# Open Dialog onRowClick [Material-Table] [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, material-table

I am using React Material-Table (https://material-table.com/#/). How can I display a dialog when I click on a table row? I tried to achieve this with onRowClick property, but I could not find appropriate examples with this property and how can I call my Dialog component with it.
Could someone help with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this, I use hooks and Dialog component from material ui for this example.
onRowClick function will change showDialog state to true and Dialog will show if showDialog is true

```
const [showDialog, setShowDialog] = useState(false);

return(
<MaterialTable
   onRowClick={(evt,rowData)=>{setShowDialog(true)}}
/>
<Dialog open={showDialog}/>
)
```